# Unable to connect to selenium from webdriverio. Got blocked by firewall

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, zscaler

I have nodejs webriverio setup to run my cucumber test-cases. I am using standalone selinium server. The selinium server is started using chrome driver. I can see response when i take http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session in browser.

When running test through webdriverio, the selinium server url http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session is getting blocked by firewall. I dont know why it is getting blocked because, accessing that url through browser is working fine without issues.

I am using

selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar

Webdriverio 4.4.0

How does wdio connect to selinium? Not through http?? I am behind corporate proxy and firewall from z-scaler.

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/ in your code, Please put you code here.

Comment: Try with `http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub` just in case. The firewall probably blocks unknown processes from accessing the network interface. You should ask your IT department for a workaround.